# GeoServer - External graphics

Tags: geoserver, sld

I want to create SLD with an external graphic in GeoServer, I used this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
 xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
 xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
 xmlns:xlink="http**strong text**://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>City Point</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>City Simple Points</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
        <Title>city</Title>
            <PointSymbolizer>
             <Graphic>
              <ExternalGraphic>
                <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="city.svg"/>
                <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
              </ExternalGraphic>
              <Size>
                <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
              </Size>
             </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

I saved the svg file in this path: `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/geoserver/data/styles/` but it doesn't work.

Comment: what does the log file show?

Comment: does anything show if you use the `burg` style

Comment: What happens if you copy the image to a directory like C:/Temp and change href="file:/C:/Temp/city.svg"?

Comment: @iant With the burg style, everything works correctly

Comment: @artwork21 I'm afraid I can save it in the directory like that because I use ubuntu and I don't have it.

Comment: now try copying the burg style and changing the file name - if that fails then either your file is in the wrong place or it is broken

Comment: In the end, the problem was with GeoServer. It works only if I don't add the workspace for the style. Thanks for the help.